# Joining all mp3 links in m3u file into a single mp3 file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mp3, join

I have an m3u file, which has links to many mp3 files online.  When I play this m3u file in a player such as vlc, it works fine as long as the internet connection is good.

My question is, what's a good way to join all the mp3 file links in the m3u file into a single mp3 file, For offline listening.

Ideally without encoding the files gain, which will only result in further loss of quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wget to retrieve, and cat to join mp3 files together.

Eg:

```
cat *.mp3 > out.mp3
```

It is trivial (and great for learning) to write "m3u-to-mp3" in any scripting language.  Just open the m3u file,  loop through each line, retrieve the files (ignoring #comments) and concatenate them together with cat.

edit: There is also some good information about using mp3wrap and ensuring the proper order in the answers to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/20507/concatenating-several-mp3-files-into-one-mp3

Comment: The link provided contradicts your answer.

Comment: No it doesn't. cat will join mp3s just fine.  The issue is the order of the files.  Since we have no idea what the file names are I provided the additional reference.